# Save Dynamically textarea values in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web, ecmascript-6, frontend

## **[Project Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdTG0.png)**

this is speed type test project.

I want the values ​​in an array when the user types the values ​​in the text area stored dynamically

This is because the values ​​that are in the **check (word) function** can be checked with textarea values. This is to see if the texts entered in the textarea are the same as word or not

this is source code:

```
// this is main text, What the user sees and types on the page
const mainText = document.getElementById("text");

const texts = {
    10: "use nation back no no those as move same again can",
    25: "labore exercitation est laborum sunt aliqua ut magna laborum sit quis laborum reprehenderit veniam ea ad in cillum aliquip fugiat sit eiusmod proident irure anim",
    50: "eu cillum proident laboris qui eiusmod amet mollit mollit amet tempor nostrud reprehenderit dolor mollit ipsum cillum qui anim aliquip ex ipsum sint labore labore sit deserunt tempor deserunt exercitation laborum in Lorem mollit sit enim enim velit qui fugiat eiusmod aliqua aute ex magna dolore mollit ex velit consectetur",
    100: "dolore esse eu mollit sunt duis sint ex ad sunt quis pariatur nostrud aliqua occaecat duis consequat do ut aliqua eu cillum cupidatat velit ea ut cillum aliqua Lorem minim Lorem pariatur magna aute culpa Lorem exercitation culpa ut Lorem nulla id qui est deserunt pariatur aliqua sunt reprehenderit laboris reprehenderit anim aliqua tempor minim velit excepteur laborum magna adipisicing reprehenderit laborum non minim fugiat do nisi cillum commodo voluptate deserunt tempor consectetur fugiat ea et cupidatat minim magna cupidatat elit adipisicing tempor velit pariatur eu consequat nisi ullamco voluptate esse do deserunt consectetur commodo fugiat aliquip in sit labore",
};

// we can access 10, 25, 50, 100 in document
const word = document.querySelectorAll(".word__length ul li a"); 

let selectedWord = "25"; // Default selected word
word.forEach((x) => {
    x.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        selectedWord = x.innerHTML;
        mainText.innerHTML = texts[selectedWord];
        check(texts[selectedWord]);
    });
});
// Set the default word when the page loads
mainText.innerHTML = texts[selectedWord];
function check(text) {
    const words = text.split(' ');
    for (const word of words) {
        
    }
}
let inputValue = textInput.value;
inputValue = inputValue.split(" ");
```

...................................................................................................

Thank You for Your Help;)

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. As for your code: the part you need to work on is the `for` loop: it is currently empty... Show your attempt, and explain what the problem is you encounter *when trying*.